# How can I use rdebug with pow rack server

Tags: ruby, rack-pow, rdebug

I'm developing Rails apps using [pow](http://pow.cx/) as the local server. I want to be able to connect to the debugger when dropping a `debugger` line in my ruby code, just as you would to webrick server.

Comment: Some rephrasing on searching the google machine found an answer. Great writeup on how to use rdebug with pow at http://m.onkey.org/using-ruby-debug-with-pow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://m.onkey.org/using-ruby-debug-with-pow provides a great, easy to follow solution.